# Navbars and liquid design

Tags: html, css

On my new website I'm really focusing on using a liquid layout. However, I can't seem to get the navbar right. At the moment I'm using a horizontal navbar built with a floating list. I have both a few buttons floating to the left and a few to the right. Now my problem is that once the window width gets too small, some of the buttons jump to the next line in the document. Something I'd like to avoid or at least make look good. Any ideas?

Comment: Please at least add some code or an example of what you're having problems with, and what you already tried to solve it. A basic example of the problem in a jsfiddle.net is always useful so we can help debug and improve it right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing an example, I'd say you should start using media queries. Find the browser width at which the menu breaks, and then add this to your CSS:

```
@media all and (max-width: ???px) {
    #yournavbar {
        /* some styles here that change your navbar /*

    }
}
```

That way, you don't have to style the navbar so that it *always* works the same way and still looks good, but you can just change the styling below (or above) a certain treshhold so that it starts to behave differently, based on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Are the li elements in the nav bar of fixed width? If yes the wrapper around them needs to have a fixed width, equal to the added withs and margins, this will prevent float drops.

Another option would be to use min-width on the whole layout to force a scroll bar, this will prevent a float drop as well.

Comment: Yea, but the whole point of liquid design is to avoid scrollbars and both solutions will result in a scrollbar.

Comment: how about positng some code? Youre question is very vague. The solutions i suggested are the way to prevent floats from dropping, this doesnt have anything to do with liquidness...